# Rcpp not sure what class return type should be. error: double not able to convert to const int&

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to use Rcpp for the first time. I have made a script in C++ that works fine independently of R, but when trying to implement it in Rcpp I am getting an error message about the return type. Here is the gist of what I've done:

```
cppSim <- '

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <math.h>
//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>
using boost::math::students_t;


using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// function to calculate p-value from a t-test

double ttestPValue(vector<double> obs1, vector<double> obs2, int nSamples){ 

    ...

    return(q);  \\ q is a double, this bit works fine
}


NumericVector powerSimulation(int nSamples,  int meanDiff, int nPerm, double pValueCutOff){

    ...

    // create vectors to hold data
    double sim1T[totalRD][nPerm]; 

    ...

    sim1T[rdmu - minRD][j] = ttestPValue(obs1, obs2, nSamples);

    double power[totalRD];
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        power[j] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalRD; i++){
        for (int sum = 0; sum < nPerm; sum ++){         
            if (sim1T[i][sum] < pValueCutOff){
               power[i] = power[i] + 1;
            }
         }
         power[i] = (power[i] / nPerm)*100;
    }

    return power; 
}'
```

To run it I am using:

```
settings=getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS=paste('-std=c++11',settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS,sep=' ')

simRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(nSamplesR = "int", meanDiffR = "int", nPermR = "int", pValueCutOffR = "double"),
                          plugin="Rcpp", 
                          settings = settings,
                          includes = cppSim,
                          body='
                          int nSamples = Rcpp::as<int>(nSamplesR);
                          int meanDiff = Rcpp::as<int>(meanDiffR);
                          int nPerm = Rcpp::as<int>(nPermR);
                          double pValueCutOff = Rcpp::as<double>(pValueCutOffR);
                          return Rcpp::wrap( cppSim(nSamples, meanDiff, nPerm, pValueCutOff));')
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
file928498473e2.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::NumericVector powerSimulation(int, int, int, double)’:
file928498473e2.cpp:165:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘double*’ to ‘const int&’ [-fpermissive]
 return power;
        ^
```

I get that my return type for power is wrong but how do I make it right? I've tried wrapping it as a NumericVector but that doesn't seem to work and I can't find an example with the same issue, as not everyone uses cxxfunction().

Comment: "I am trying to use Rcpp for the first time."  Welcome!  I (somewhat strongly) recommend you give the [Brief Introduction to Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette a read.  You should not need `cxxfunction()`.

Comment: You almost certainly want to declare `power` as a `std:vector<double>`. In fact, unless `totalRD` is a compile-time constant, your current code is invalid anyway.

Comment: Please do not use the `inline` package. For help writing code with Rcpp attributes, please see: ["To Rcpp Attributers and Beyond from Inline"](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/to-rcpp-attributes-and-beyond-from-inline/) (Disclaimer: I wrote this.)

Comment: @tsv are you planning on cleaning this up by using Rcpp Attributes and making it reproducible? If not, we can't really help out.

Comment: @coatless I am usually an R user, I have made a script in C++ that works (although I don't know what compile-time constant and things mean so maybe I'm doing it wrong there??) I'm now trying to put my code into R as the original example that I saw you seemed to be able to do that. Do I need to include Rcpp Attributes within the C++ script in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
double power[totalRD];
```

into

```
std::vector<double> power(totalRD);
```